# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0, get this Error on deleting last image flutter:-

Tags: flutter, entity-framework, dart, flutter-animation

I have five images and when I tap on any image, it opens in full screen and we can swipe to other image left/right, and when I delete any image the particular image gets deleted and then it goes to next image, till now it is working fine but when there is only image left after deleting all other and when I delete that one single image too it gives ERROR: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0. How to delete that last image from index.Pls help... Thanks.

```
  Widget deleteBtn(BuildContext context) {
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
return new Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
child: IconButton(
icon: Icon(
  Icons.delete_forever_outlined,
  color: const Color(0xFF227770),
  size: 35,
),
onPressed: () async {
  var fileUrl =
  Uri.decodeFull(Path.basename(widget.imageList[_currentIndex]))
      .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'(\?alt).*'), '');
  try {
    firebase_storage.Reference photoRef = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref().storage.refFromURL(widget.imageList[_currentIndex]);

    await photoRef.delete().then((value)  {
      widget.imageList.removeAt(_currentIndex);

      _pageController.nextPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 10) , curve: Curves.easeInOut);

    });
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    print("Cant delete" +e);
     }
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
      .update({
    "images": FieldValue.arrayRemove([widget.imageList[_currentIndex]])
  });
},
),
  );

  }
```

Comment: it means that the list is empty

Comment: yes, and I want to pop back to previous screen from there when I delete that last image and update the UI state. How can I do that ? pls guide.

Comment: state management: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options . I'd suggest learning provider first then learn bloc afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You can check on your array length and reduce it by one.

Comment: I am just a beginner, pls tell me where to add this line where I can check and on deletion of last image  I can pop back to previous screen

Comment: hello I got it, now I am with no errors, just one help now. on deleting of last image I want to pop back to previous screen

Comment: After deleting an image, you should check if the list is empty now or not, if it is empty you should call Navigator.of(context).pop();